# Draw map tiles one at a time

Tags: sprite-kit, tvos

I'm developing a SpriteKit based game for tvOS.  I'd like to be able to see the tiles of floor for the map drawn displayed one at a time.  I can 't get that to work.  Below is a sample class file that exhibits my issue.  No matter what delay I put on the NSTimer, the tiles all appear at once.

Am I missing something straightforward?

Thanks

Ken

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene
-(void)drawFloorNode:(NSTimer *)timer{
  NSDictionary *thisDict=[timer userInfo];
  int x =[[thisDict objectForKey:@"xval"] intValue];
  int y =[[thisDict objectForKey:@"yval"] intValue];
  SKSpriteNode *myFloor=[[SKSpriteNode alloc]   initWithImageNamed:@"Floor1.png"];
  myFloor.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0, 0.5);
  myFloor.size=CGSizeMake(64, 64);
  myFloor.position=CGPointMake(x,self.frame.size.height - (y*64) - 128);
  myFloor.zPosition=-1;
  [self addChild:myFloor];
  [timer invalidate];
  timer=nil;
}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

  SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];

  myLabel.text = @"Hello, World!";
  myLabel.fontSize = 65;
  myLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                               CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

  [self addChild:myLabel];

  for(int y=0;y<9;y++){
    for(int x=0;x<64*15+1;x+=64){
        NSMutableDictionary *myDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc ]init];
        [myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"xval"];
        [myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y] forKey:@"yval"];
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(drawFloorNode:) userInfo:myDict repeats:NO];

    }
}

}

@end
```

Comment: this is because you are creating a ton of timers all starting at the same time and finishing 1 second after,  the current way you are doing it will not work,  what you may want to do instead is load up all of your tiles into an array of some sort,  and that have the timer repeat,  and everytime it repeats,  it takes off the top most item to draw, or increase the scheduledTimer time based on the node count,  so 1st node is 1 second,  2nd node is 2,  but I do not know how many timers are actually allowed on the stack, so this is a bad approach

Comment: OK.  That helped a lot.  I did put them in an array inside the double loop, then modified the timer to repeat and the selector to pop them out of the array.    Only had to use the one timer.  Thanks!

Comment: you shouldnt never be using nstimer  inside of a spritekit game.  you have an update loop that is constantly giving you your current time.  you should be leveraging that..  or SKAction